# How to copy the top 10 most recent files from one directory to another?

Tags: linux, awk, copy, ls

Al my html files reside here :

```
/home/thinkcode/myfiles/html/
```

I want to move the newest 10 files to `/home/thinkcode/Test`

I have this so far. Please correct me. I am looking for a one-liner!

```
ls -lt *.htm | head -10 | awk '{print "cp "$1" "..\Test\$1}' | sh
```

Comment: You could use `xargs` and avoid `awk`+`sh` (feels ugly) or probably use `find ... -exec` and run just one command.

Comment: I could do the find but was just wondering how to do the same using awk!

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) and [BashFAQ/099](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ls -lt *.htm | head -10 | awk '{print "cp " $9 " ../Test/"$9}' | sh
```

Comment: `ls` is notoriously bad about listing file names that have special characters in them. Also, parsing the output of `ls -l` is fraught with danger. Better to write a small perl script which will stat all of the files and sort the results by date. If you must use `ls`, at least leave off the `-l` argument... `ls -t *.html | head -10` would work just as well.

Comment: Is the `|sh` at the end necessary?

Comment: Does not work when there is spaces in file names. Use `ls -t *.htm |head -10 |awk '{print "cp -- \"" $0 "\" ../Test/"}'` |sh` instead

Comment: Could you explain what your code does?

Answer (score 8):

`cp` seems to understand back-ticked commands. So you could use a command like this one to copy the 10 latest files to another folder like e.g. `/test`:

```
cp `ls -t *.htm | head -10` /test
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want

Comment: Works great until you have a file with a space in its name, or even worse, a file named `; rm -fr --no-preserve-root / ; .htm` in your folder.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a version which doesn't use `ls`. It should be less vulnerable to strange characters in file names:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.html' -print0 
     \| xargs -0 stat --printf "%Y\t%n\n" 
     \| sort -n 
     \| tail  -n 10 
     \| cut -f 2 
     \| xargs cp -t ../Test/
```

I used `find` for a couple of reasons:

1) if there are too many files in a directory, bash will balk at the wildcard expansion*.

2) Using the `-print0` argument to `find` gets around the problem of bash expanding whitespace in a filename in to multiple tokens.

* Actually, bash shares a memory buffer for its wildcard expansion and its environment variables, so it's not strictly a function of the number of file names, but rather the total length of the file names and environment variables. Too many environment variables => no wildcard expansion.

EDIT: Incorporated some of @glennjackman's improvements. Kept the initial use of `find` to avoid the use of the wildcard expansion which might fail in a large directory.

Comment: +1 for not using ls. Can be a bit simpler: `stat -c "%Y\t%n" *.html | sort -n | tail -10 | cut -d " " -f 2- | xargs cp -t ../Test`

Comment: @glennjackman:  is the cut at tab character, which printed as " " when you pasted?

Comment: Actually, tab is the default delimiter for `cut`, so you can omit `-d` altogether.

Comment: This solution is indeed useful when wildcard expansion fails. One would use `cp -u -t` (mind the order of the flags) to copy only when the source file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing.

Answer (score 5):

```
ls -lt *.html | head -10 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -i cp {} DestDir
```

In the above example `DestDir` is the destination directory for the copy.

Add `-t` after xargs to see the commands as they execute. I.e.,  `xargs -i -t cp {} DestDir`.

For more information check out the [xargs command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs).

*EDIT*: As pointed out by @DennisWilliamson (and also checking the current man page) re the `-i` option `This option is  deprecated; use -I instead.`.

Also, both solutions presented depend on the filenames in questions don't contain any blanks or tabs.

Comment: how to copy the files over to the ../test directory?

Comment: ls -lt *.htm | head -10 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs cp * ../Test/ ? Doesn't work. How to collect the file-names from the pipe and feed to the copy command?

Comment: Updated my answer to address your questions

Comment: @Levon, i was commenting on ThinkCode's comment. he did `cp *`

Comment: `print $NF` and `print $9` both fail if filenames include spaces or tabs. `xargs -i` is deprecated - use `xargs -I {}` instead.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Useful information, so noted. I'll update my answer, thanks!