# How to copy the latest 2 directories from one directory to another?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i found how to copy the latest files from one directory to another, but i need to copy 2 latest directories to another directory. How to do it? i tried to change commands that works with files, but they doesn't work with directories

```
cp -pr "`ls -dtr1 /dir1/* | tail -2`" /dir2/
cp: cannot stat ‘/dir1/03\n/dir1/01’: No such file or directory


ls -lt /dir1/* | head -2 | awk '{print "cp " $1 " /dir2/"$1}' | sh
cp: cannot stat ‘/dir1/01:’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘total’: No such file or directory


ls -lt /dir1/* | head -2 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -i cp {} /dir2/
cp: cannot stat ‘/dir1/01:’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘0’: No such file or directory
```

Links:
[How to copy the top 10 most recent files from one directory to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604391/how-to-copy-the-top-10-most-recent-files-from-one-directory-to-another)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195304/how-do-i-copy-the-latest-file-from-one-directory-to-another

Comment: Include a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo "$(/bin/ls -d1tr */ | tail -2)" | xargs -I % sh -c 'cp -R "%" tmp'
```

Sort the output of `ls` by timestamp, taken one entry at a time and in reverse order, listing only directories within the current directory. Take the last 2 output lines. Pass the result to `xargs` substituting the names into the shell command to copy the directories into another directory called `tmp`.

**Update**:
add some quotes to fix problems with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: Wrapping this inside an `echo` breaks it if the name of the directory has spaces embedded.

Comment: @user1934428 good point, I updated to add proper quoting that should fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

With your approach with cp, tail will work with -1 only, as more that one are returned with /n symbol as separator and not as a list:

```
cp -p "`ls -dtr /dir1/* | tail -1`" /dir2/
```

So there is a solution to overcome tail adding /n and replacing it with space using tr.

This is the working command for more than one file:

```
cp -rp `ls -dtr /dir1/* | tail -2| tr '\n' ' ' ` /dir2/
```